# What does MSW stand for in a book on University of Michigan sports?

Tags: united-states, abbreviations

I am researching a relative whose name appears in the book [Michigan: Champions of the West](https://books.google.com/books?id=fd87BHQ4VrkC). Much of the book consists of names, abbreviations, and years. Here is an excerpt:

```
Bailey, Debi       VB   1986
Bailey, Donald A.  FB   1964,65,66
Bailey, Eric R.    MSW  1989,90,91,92
```

I can imagine FB standing for football or fullback. What does MSW stand for?

Other abbreviations are SB, IHO, MTN, MBK, and MTR.

Comment: MSW can mean _Master of Social Work_, and MSU did offer that degree in the late 80s and early 90s, although I doubt that would make it into a sports records book..

Comment: Where are you getting the information?  The book should have a list of abbreviations in the front matter.  (I understand you may be seeing someone else's extracts and that they didn't bother to copy the abbreviations.)

Comment: I used Google Books and provide a link in the question. I was not able to find a key to the abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I did look at Google Books via your link to confirm that the preview there wouldn't show you a page with the abbreviations on it.  It's useful to state these things explicitly in your Q so people can see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a list of people who competed in sports. So in your example it seems likely that VB is volleyball, FB is football, and MSW is men's swimming. I would presume that any three-letter abbreviation in that list which starts with M is men's something. So MTN men's tennis, MTR men's track, etc.

The years are presumably when the person competed in the listed sport.

Edit: More likely meanings: IHO intramural hockey, SB softball, MBK men's basketball.

Comment: It's easy to cross-check your guesses by doing a Google Search. Some of  Eric Bailey's high school records are listed here: https://www.mhsaa.com/Sports/Boys-Swimming-Diving/Individual-Champions/Division-1-Class-A and for college here: http://grfx.cstv.com/photos/schools/mich/sports/m-swim/auto_pdf/2015-16/misc_non_event/sdm-record-book.pdf and